# Git Workflow: Share code between computers without pushing to public repo

Tags: git, workflow

I work at a company which uses Git for our version control. We're using a hosted repo service (Beanstalk) as our internal "public" (by that I mean accessible to the whole dev team) repo. I have two computers that I normally work on for writing code. I like using some of the history rewriting features of Git, specifically rebasing and amending commits, but I really don't like using them after I've pushed something to a published branch. Yet, I need to be able to share code between these two computers, and preferably no one else.

What I'd like is an easy way to share my code between the two computers, without having to share it with everyone else. I have considered Airdrop (both computers are Macs), and ssh. What would be the suggested way of achieving this, while taking advantage of git's distributed nature?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can push, fetch and pull between the machines freely assuming you have ssh access between them:

```
git push computer2:projects/prog HEAD:tmp
```

or, if you are on computer2:

```
git pull computer1:projects/prog HEAD
```

or

```
git fetch computer1:prj/prog branch1:t1
git fetch computer1:prj/prog branch2:t2
git merge t1 t2
```

or

```
git fetch computer1:prj/prog branch1 branch2 branch3
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

and so on... See `git help fetch` for more examples.

Comment: BTW, git-daemon and WebDAV setups also allow push, but are harder to setup and might need system-wide administration permissions.

Comment: Still `git instaweb` can be used to simply export a Git repo if there is no ssh or it is blocked by a firewall. A httpd is needed, of course (apache, lighttpd, mongoose, plackup and webrick, according to the manpage of instaweb)

Comment: Can one local branch be set up to track multiple remotes?

Comment: @s73v3r: no. Only one remote for a branch. AFAIK, it was never asked before. I, personally, seldom use branch tracking, with `git pull` being as capable as it is: just do `git pull remote remote-branch`

Answer (score 1):

You can run an instant git  server on one of the machines, either using git-daemon or something like this: https://gist.github.com/1525217

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you cannot create temp working branches that are clearly indicated as such on the remote repo, but if you want an alternative and both computers are connected by network and accessible via ssh, you could possibly set up either or both of them as additional remotes and push from one to the other in any direction. It may be confusing to get it right the first time though as you do not want to push to the wrong remote.

Comment: Here's the biggest question I have with that idea: Is it a problem to set two machines up as remotes of each other? So Dev1 would push to remote Dev2, and Dev2 would push to remote Dev1?

Comment: not at all, if you know how to set up and work with multiple remotes. You don't even need git daemon if you can connect to either repo by ssh://user@`machine-name-or-ip`:`path-to-repo`