# How to share local changes without git push?

Tags: git

I'm using `git` in my project. Sometimes I need to share my modified changes with my colleagues or to different PC, but I don't want to push those changes. He will take my code and modify something and then will push that code.
For now I manually give him file via mail or send in pen drive. I want this to be done via `git`.
Can I do like `git commit` and then share without `git push`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Workflow: Share code between computers without pushing to public repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419448/git-workflow-share-code-between-computers-without-pushing-to-public-repo)

Comment: Create a branch and push to the branch, get the colleague to checkout your branch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use git-bundle for keeping development in sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635952/how-to-use-git-bundle-for-keeping-development-in-sync)

Comment: @Laazo I tried this, but for minor changes is it good practice to create separate brnach?

Comment: It's good practice to create a branch for any changes that may leave the main branch unstable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share a git feature (or topic) branch with multiple developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496358/how-to-share-a-git-feature-or-topic-branch-with-multiple-developers)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can save the changes to a patch file with

```
git diff > /path/to/file.patch
```

This supposes that your changes are unstaged. Use `git diff --cached` if they are staged. I would not commit them, since your colleague is going to do that and you'll run into conflicts otherwise.

You can send this file via mail or whatever, and your colleague can apply those changes with

```
git apply /path/to/file.patch
```

Comment: OP has asked via git.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar ,it uses a git mechanism to share and apply change sets without pushing to a repository, which is also a requirement of OP.

Comment: But you mentioned share file via mail.